# Is there a way to filter posts created with the Ask Wizard in the Data Explorer?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, data-explorer, ask-wizard

Stack Overflow recently re-debuted the Ask Wizard for use by new users.

Using the Data Explorer, is there any (current or planned) way to query posts that were created using this tool?

Answer (score 7):

Because [the feature launched yesterday](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421038/the-ask-wizard-2022-has-graduated) (25-Oct 2022), there won’t be any data for these posts in SEDE until the next refresh on Sunday 30-Oct circa 3:00 UTC. However, it should be rather trivial to query these posts once they’re available in the data because [there will be a special `PostHistoryTypeId` value associated with questions coming from the tool](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421038/the-ask-wizard-2022-has-graduated#comment931561_421041):

> We are now planning to include `PostHistoryTypeId 66 = CreatedFromWizard` in SEDE data and site exports moving forward. The data will be retroactive to the beginning of the test earlier this year (but will not include data from the 2018 wizard).

This likely makes finding these posts in SEDE as simple as:

```sql
SELECT * FROM PostHistory WHERE PostHistoryTypeId = 66
```

Comment: This is using a new PostHistoryTypeId (66) which is created when the question is asked from the wizard. That type (and the wizard) have existed since March - it just graduated to "not an experiment" status yesterday. It looks like it's just not exposed in SEDE right now, so you'd need to change this to a feature request if you want that exposed.

Comment: Yaakov [commented on an answer to that MSO post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421038/the-ask-wizard-2022-has-graduated#comment931561_421041) to confirm that this is planned: "We are now planning to include `PostHistoryTypeId 66 = CreatedFromWizard` in SEDE data and site exports moving forward. The data will be retroactive to the beginning of the test earlier this year (but will not include data from the 2018 wizard)." (cc @animuson)

Comment: @V2Blast I was just about to comment that. :) I'm sure they'll be happy with how much easier this is than using the Comment text.

Comment: Quite lovely indeed! Much better than trying to tackle this with the `Comment` field the way I currently have it. Edits incoming.

Comment: Rather than leaving information that's outdated/no longer necessary in your answer with strikeout formatting, you should just edit your answer to read as if it were always the best version of itself. Anyone interested in older versions of the answer can view the revision history.